# How to get wget to include date & time stamp in a working local copy of a webpage index file

Tags: windows, wget

I have a report that needs downloaded on a daily basis.  I'd like to download this file once per per day, and have that file end in report_[date][time].html

example code

```
wget -k -p -O C:\Users\[user]\Desktop\New\report_%date%%time%.html www.report.com
```

I have tried multiple combinations such as

```
report_date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S
```

and

```
report_yyyymmdd_hhnnss
```

without any luck.

Is it possible to give wget a date/timestamp within an output file?

Comment: This is a Windows question (judging from your backslash usage). It's got nothing to do with `wget`. How would you create any file in windows with the date and time as part of the filename? (BTW if you want to know how to do this in Unix, that I do know...)

Comment: Windows CMD options are whats needed.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget --output-document=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.file 
www.report.com/reports/report.file
```

The command “wget” will download the file “report.file” from exemplary destination “www.report.com/reports/“ an save it with the (output) document name that is The current date in the format YYYY-MM-DD with the arbitrary extension “.file”. The date command fetches the full time stamp of the operation. %Y, %m and %d take the year, month and day parts of that, respectively. The apostrophes and quotation marks are required to format the output as string. An examplary output for today would be “2020-08-15.file”.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation to your code?

Comment: The command “wget” will download the file “report.file” from exemplary destination “www.report.com/reports/“ an save it with the (output) document name that is The current date in the format YYYY-MM-DD with the arbitrary extension “.file”.
The date command fetches the full time stamp of the operation. 
%Y, %m and %d take the year, month and day parts of that, respectively. The apostrophes and quotation marks are required to format the output as string. An examplary output for today would be “2020-08-15.file”.

Comment: I really wonder how the question for an explanation of the code by @Skully gets an upvote, but neither the explanation nor the code do. Stackoverflow sometimes is a bit odd.

Comment: Good answers include explanation and details, not just 2 lines of code.  You should edit your explanation into the answer.

Comment: I don't quite see the need for it, but here you go.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you **YYYY-MM-DD.png**

```
wget --output-document=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%.png www.webpage.com
```

Comment: Defining the output-documents name is the right idea.
However, the date format seems a bit odd to me.