# Cron job to download an online XML file but rename it each time

Tags: xml, cron

I need to download a copy of an XML file as per this question answered [Download online XML file using cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225587/download-online-xml-file-using-cron)

As an example:

```
0 13 * * *  wget -O /home/html/myname/xmldownloads/ http://somedomain.com/somexmlfile.xml
```

However I need to run the cron command in such a way that the downloaded file is given a different filename each time so that it is not overwritten. (ideally appended with the date)

Is this even possible?
Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169897/5428

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63403913/14419

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append current date to the filename via Cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110663/append-current-date-to-the-filename-via-cron)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better solution. To create multiple cron jobs with different filenames in the local download folder.

Comment: Do you mean adding 365 lines every year (366 if lap year)?

Comment: @Álvaro González no I just needed to rotate 3 files and compare them with each other sequentially before the next batch the next day. My solution is now adequate. I’ll mark this as resolved when I can